# How do you create a class without knowing how many variables you will need for that class?

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering how you would go about creating a class to store strings and integers without knowing how many strings or integer you will have. For example lets say I make a class call Person.

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Age As Integer
    Public Property Gender As String
End Class
```

Now, to create a new person and give them their details I would do:

```
Dim Human As New Person With {.Name = "Bob", .Age=20, .Gender="Male"}
```

Well what if `Bob` has more information than just his Name, Age, and Gender? What if Bob also has a Height of 6ft and a Weight of 200lbs? How would I include this information in my Person class once its already been created?

What is this problem even called in the programming world?

Comment: You could add another property of type `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` or the like and then you could store arbitrary data against the `String` keys. You need to consider exactly how you would persist such data though.

Comment: Maybe if you explain why just adding a new property and changing it's initialization could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is called the open closed principle.

The solution depends on how bedded you are to it/SOLID principles. Things that spring to mind:

- Simply adding the fields at a later date (this will violate the open
  closed principle)
- Extending the class (a new type of person with those new properties
  for example)

The problem with the former (and a reason for OCP) is that it could have dependency implications for not only yourself but others. For example if you add property Age and start writing functionality that uses it what happens when you have a process that needs Age and you haven't set it.

Comment: How do I add the fields at a later date? For my purpose I don't need to reference it again, I just need it once to be displayed and thats it

Comment: If you have access to the class your options are to simply add the property to Person, or create a new class that extends Person that implements the additional properties. If it is a sealed class or you cannot change it then you're looking at extending it (inheritance) or decorate it (decorator pattern). Always keeping potential dependency issues for the new properties in mind.